# Flutter Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have this issue when switch to another page (from login to dashboard page).

The error:

Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.

...
The specific parent that did not update after having one or more children forcibly removed due to GlobalKey reparenting is:

- Expanded(flex: 1)

the code:

```
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final FocusNode passFocus = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode emailFocus = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);

    return authProvider.status == Status.Authenticating
        ? Loading()
        : Scaffold(
          key: _key,
            body: ...
```

and

```
class LayoutTemplate extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _key,
      body: ...
```

and this is my navigation service:

```
class NavigationService {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey =
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  Future<dynamic> navigateTo(String routeName, {ArgumentsClass arguments}) {
    return navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(routeName, arguments: arguments);
  }

  Future<dynamic> globalNavigateTo(String routeName, BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(routeName);
  }

  void goBack() {
    return navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have created a Key in your navigation service and sent it everywhere
scaffold key is something unique you have to create and use it only in one specific page

Comment: In LayoutTemplate class I have the Navigator child: child:Navigator(
                    key: locator<NavigationService>().navigatorKey,
                    onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
                    initialRoute: HomeRoute,
                  ),